# Proving a vector space of analytic functions is infinite-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the set of all functions f(t) which are analytic for $|t| < 1,$ that is, $f(t)$ has a power series expansion $f(t) =a_{0}+a_{1}t+a_2{t^{2}}+\cdots$ which converges for $|t|<1$. Show that $V$ is a vector space, and that its dimension is infinite. Hint: $V$ contains all polynomials

---

First, I tried to show $V$ is a vector space using the following argument:

- If $f, g \in V$, then $f_0 + f_1t + f_2t^2 + \cdots$ converges for $|t| < 1$ and $g_0 + g_1t + g_2t^2 + \cdots$ converges for $|t| < 1$. By properties of convergence, their sum converges to the sum of their limit points for $|t| < 1$. Thus, closure under addition follows.
- If $f \in V$, then $cf\in V$ since the limit point of $cf$ will just be a constant times the limit point of $f$, which follows by properties of limits.

Is this correct so far? I have no idea how to show $V$ is infinite-dimensional. I haven't been able to make use of the hint at all.

Comment: $\mathbf{Hint}$: How many linearly independent polynomials are there?

Comment: I would guess infinitely many. But I don't know why. Did I do the first part correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is correct. For the second part let us show that $1,t,t^{2},...$ are linearly independent. If $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} c_it^{i}=0$ on $\{t:|t|<1\}$ then every $t$ with $|t|<1$ is a solution of the polynomial equation $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} c_it^{i}=0$. A non-zero polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ zeros. Hence this polynomial must be the zero polynomial and we must have $c_i=0$ for all $i$.